# Why is a keystroke included in alerts?

Tags: gnome-shell

When I press a key on my keyboard I get the alert sound. That was not the case under unity. To stop the sound I have to turn off all alerts.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple annoying faults with the desktops for all versions. I suppose they were caused by alterations.

The problems were solved by reinstalling Ubuntu.